# Как выдать фото по хештэгу из instagram на своей странице?

Tags: jquery, instagram, instagram-api

Хочу создать страницу и поставить поисковик. При вводе там слова, чтобы на странице выдавал результаты, фотки, из инстаграм по введенному тэгу.

Как могу добиться этого?

Покопался в интернете, но так и не смог понять. Могу выдавать все фотки какого то юзера, но не могу давать поиск по тэгу.

Буду очень рад помощи!

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get({

    url:  "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+hashtag+"/media/recent?access_token=594843268.5b9e1e6.e348dab77134bf4a63bb2cccdbc5a8d",

    success: function(data){

    var res = JSON.parse(data);

    for (var d in res) {
    /// ....
    }

}});
```

Как-то так приблизительно.

Только `access_token` мой не юзайте, хотя лучше его перетру!

Answer (score 1):

Можно без токена.

```
<?php
$insta_tag  = 'котики';
$client_id  = 'f2777521ba194d1f824fcb03a2ef82b1'; //client_id instagram api
$img_count  = 12;

//запрос к api
$imgs = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/".$insta_tag."/media/recent/?client_id=".$client_id."&amp;count=".$img_count);
//декодирум json-ответ
$array = json_decode($imgs);
//функция для преобразования объекта в многомерный массив
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }
    if (is_array($d)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    } else {
        return $d;
    }
}
$array_new = objectToArray($array);
//данные из массива
foreach ($array_new['data'] as $img) {
    $img_link   = $img['link'];
    $img_src    = $img['images']['low_resolution']['url']; //thumbnail, low_resolution, standard_resolution
?>
<a href="<? echo $img_link; ?>" target="_blank" class="">
    <img src="<? echo $img_src; ?>" alt="">
</a>
```